# POST in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I have a WCF Service that I'm trying to develop in a REST-based fashion. Because of this, I have an operation that requires a POST operation. I've noticed that Silverlight does not support WebHttpBinding. My question is, how can you do a POST in Silverlight to a REST-based service? Especially a service that takes an object as a parameter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

here is a blog where get and post to REST services are described.

http://technicalitiesblog.blogspot.com/2010/03/using-get-post-in-silverlight-restful.html